# How to select and install Semantic Web tools

Tags: java, mysql, eclipse, jena, semantic-web

I'm beginner in semantic web, actually try to build web, I built my ontology, now I try to upload it into MySQL.

Which Java I must use (Java EE SDK or Java JDK) and which Jena (only Jena or Jena TDB OR Jena SDB)?

Answer (score 0):

MySQL will use its Connector-J JDBC driver.  I don't know what the upload software looks like,  but that's how it can connect to MySQL.  It'll assume that the schema's been created before you try to INSERT any data.

Perhaps this link can help you make your decision:

[http://answers.semanticweb.com/questions/506/pros-and-cons-for-different-jena-backends-sdb-vs-tdb](https://web.archive.org/web/20160302052302/http://answers.semanticweb.com:80/questions/506/pros-and-cons-for-different-jena-backends-sdb-vs-tdb)

It appears to be an SO-like Q&A site for semantic web.  That might be useful for your future work.  It could be a better source for answers that SO.

Comment: thanks for your answer , I know I must use JDBC and I make successfully connected before , but I try to make connect in order to  semantic web project and sure I use JDBC but the connecting is unsuccessfully so I ask which the type of jena  I must use??

Answer (score 0):

Normally, use Apache Jena TDB.  It's faster and scales better.  Use SDB when you must use an SQL database.

Comment: hi @AndyS , can I use jena (http://sourceforge.net/projects/jena/files/Jena/Jena-2.5.6/) or it's be old ?? and does MySQL is compatible with SDB? I just want to built webpage depend on semantic web technology and I built my ontology using protege?